# Wget how to recursively download a website

Tags: python, shell, web-crawler, sh, wget

I am trying to download an website and its hyperlinks, and list out only the links whose content has "search" word in it. how can i achieve this?

I have tried of recursively doing it via `wget -r --no-parent example.com`, but that seems to download the png's, css's and xml's too, which i think i do not need for my search

```
wget -r https://stackoverflow.com
--2019-10-17 13:11:47--  https://stackoverflow.com/
Resolving stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)... 151.101.65.69, 151.101.1.69, 151.101.129.69, ...
Connecting to stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)|151.101.65.69|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 115049 (112K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘stackoverflow.com/index.html’

stackoverflow.com/index.html                100%[========================================================================================>] 112.35K   340KB/s    in 0.3s    

2019-10-17 13:11:48 (340 KB/s) - ‘stackoverflow.com/index.html’ saved [115049/115049]

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2019-10-17 13:11:48--  https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt
Reusing existing connection to stackoverflow.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2094 (2.0K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘stackoverflow.com/robots.txt’

stackoverflow.com/robots.txt                100%[========================================================================================>]   2.04K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-10-17 13:11:48 (5.23 MB/s) - ‘stackoverflow.com/robots.txt’ saved [2094/2094]

--2019-10-17 13:11:48--  https://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml
Reusing existing connection to stackoverflow.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 617 [text/xml]
Saving to: ‘stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml’

stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml            100%[========================================================================================>]     617  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-10-17 13:11:49 (20.2 MB/s) - ‘stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml’ saved [617/617]

--2019-10-17 13:11:49--  https://stackoverflow.com/feeds
```

Any other optimal way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: why you add tag `python` if you don't use python in your code ? Maybe first create code in python.

Answer (score 0):

WGET has few options that can provide filtering.

The '--accept ACCLST' and '--reject REJLIST' can be used to specify file suffixes to accept/reject. This can be used to limit by file types - eliminate images, css, etc.

There is no option to evaluate the content by searching for keywords (e.g., 'search') without downloading it. Two options to consider:

1. Download everything, then remove (or ignore) any file not matching search criteria.
2. Use scripting engine (python scrapy, Perl) to write customized spider. Much more work, but will provide the exact functionality.

Side note: consider using '--mirror' instead of '-r'. It will also activate timestamping, which can help reduce re-run times.